# How to avoid decimal rounding in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how I should avoid decimal rounding in javascript 
suppose I have input like

```
input : 99999999999.999999 
Expected output : 99999999999.999999
```

but i am getting output like

```
 100000000000
```

here, internally javascript rounding the decimal place.
please let me know how should I avoid this javascript rounding???.

For example:

```
var test = 99999999999.999999;
console.log(test); //This will print 100000000000 instead
```

Comment: show us your javascript / jquery and html.

Comment: Can you please show us some javascript code? How this is transformed on your side? A jsfiddle example, could help as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I did edit your question and add some code example, of what you mean @Shivkumar

Comment: @john thanks for editing your getting absolutely right i want to avoid this rounding

Answer (score 3):

As @Aliendroid suggested, you can use the [BigDecimal.js](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) library. In my perspective, this is the best way to handle double and floats in JavaScript

To answer to your question more specifically, you can actually do this:

```
var test_number = new BigDecimal('99999999999.999999'); 
console.log(test_number.setScale(6).toString());
```

and to your original question:

> please let me know how should I avoid this javascript rounding???

Well you can't as there is not double number in JavaScript, only float. So for example if you do something like this:

```
console.log(99999999999.99); //This is a float number
```

This will actually output: `99999999999.99`

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT Rounding

It is floating point error

learn floating point number in programming !

use string if needed and some Big number library

Ref:

http://floating-point-gui.de/

https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed in stackoverflow as they may become dead links. consider adding more info to your answer

Comment: Arash, agree with you! But this is not a link only answer. This is an answer and it has some references. So +1  for @Aliendroid from me :)

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis Sorry john I don't see the websites linked look like a reference. Are they something like MDN as a reference for JavaScript?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not saying that it is the best answer. Of course solutions with code will be much better. I am just saying that it is not a bad answer.